# Extract Sub-strings from String with FILTERXML

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

Using Excel 365

I have a small VBA user defined function to parse a string into sub-strings based on the comma as the separator.  I am trying to replace the UDF with a worksheet formula to make a workbook that is macro-free.

The UDF is:

```
Public Function parsee(s As String)
    Dim i As Long, arr, a
    
    arr = Split(s, ",")
    ReDim output(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(arr) + 1)
    
    i = 1
    For Each a In arr
        output(1, i) = a
        i = i + 1
    Next a
    
    parsee = output
    
End Function
```

In Excel 365 this spills across in a fashion analogous to `TextToColumns`:

[image]

Based on this previous post:

[extract substrings from string using filterxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml)

I have been using:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

This works the same way unless the input string contains an **&** character *(like the string in **A2**)*.  In this case `FILTERXML()` returns *#VALUE!*

Is there an easy fix to get `FILTERXML()` to accept the **&** like any other character ??

Comment: Only hit this problem once myself. Funny enough `XPATH` itself does allow for the ampersand to be used literally, but it's the `XML` that will not handle it well. Along with the ampersand, `FILTERXML()` does not like the *less than* sign much either, which needs to be escaped with `&lt;`. Nice question, good material to update the linked question too. Upvoted.

Comment: @JvdV  Thank you very much for your comments.....I think your post that I quoted is a great tutorial for which I also thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `&` with `&amp;`

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"&","&amp;"),",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!